# The script does not work Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phantomjs

I running this script on php:

```
<?
echo $result = shell_exec("phantomjs \script.js");
?>
```

script.js:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();


page.open("http://livescore.in/", function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);  
    }
});
```

php file, phantom.js, script.js lie in the same folder.

> PhantomJS version - 2.2.1

As a result, the script is loaded indefinitely.

Comment: What is `\script`? I would expect either `script` or `\\script`, but not `\script`.

Comment: Does the script work correctly when you're executing it from the terminal instead of php? If not then you should tackle one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of problem is most probably incorrect file paths. The simplest solution in your case is to set full paths to phantomjs binary and script.

```
<?php
    echo $result = shell_exec("/path/to/work/folder/phantomjs /path/to/work/folder/script.js");
?>
```

To find out the full path: log in to your server, navigate to the working folder and then issue command

```
pwd
```

The output of that command is the path that needs to be used in `shell_exec`.
This way you won't get confused in paths and script will always run. But I'd suggest you take a moment and read up on [absolute/relative](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12f/notes/160_pathnames.html#absolute-and-relative-pathnames) paths in Linux.

This should also work if all files are in the same folder:

```
<?php
echo $result = shell_exec("phantomjs script.js");
?>
```